# How to rebuild civicrm admin menu?

Tags: drupal, upgrade, menu, global-menu

I just upgraded civicrm from version `4.5.8` to `4.6.6`, and I found that the menu is looking different. I tried clearing cache, also tried manual deletion of template files under `files/civicrm/templates_c/`.

[image]

Comment: In order to rebuild the civicrm menu you can simply hit this url `<your_site_name>/civicrm/menu/rebuild`

Comment: @JitendraPurohit that does clear cache and rebuilds menu, but didn't fix that issue. I having this issue in multiple other sites as well.

Comment: have you tried clearing the CMS cache as well -- `drush cc all` in drupal

Comment: yes I have to manually rebuild it in database. clearing cache doesn't fix it. anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the query for creating `Support menu` [parent item] didn't get executed. Had to run the sql query manually. This fixed the menu issue.

`vim civicrm/sql/civicrm_navigation.mysql +605`

```
INSERT INTO civicrm_navigation
    ( domain_id, url, label, name, permission, permission_operator, parent_id, is_active, has_separator, weight )
VALUES
    ( @domainID, NULL, 'Support', 'Support', NULL, '',  NULL, '1', NULL, 110);
```